# Google sign_in not working in debug mode but working in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Google sign-in to work in both release and debug mode, you need to update your SHA-1 and SHA-256 key for release and debug mode on firebase.

Comment: Please elaborate. Let me Tell you what I am trying to do. I gave implemented Google sign without firebase using Google Cloud Console. And I have implemented firebase also in my app to upload file. Before the firebase implementation, Google sign_in was working fine.  But not now.

Comment: @AmanMishra Have you updated your SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys on your firebase console? If not, please update them. Make sure to provide release as well as debug mode of the keys.